# convert date string to timestamp

Tags: node.js, timestamp

is there any way to convert date string `Tue Feb 23 2016 20:11:42 GMT+0200 (EET)` to timestamp in nodejs?

I was trying to use moment.js with this:

```
moment('Tue Feb 23 2016 20:11:42 GMT+0200 (EET)', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').valueOf()
```

but it returned NaN to me. Maybe its impossible?

Answer (score 19):

There's no need for moment.js

```
var d = new Date("Tue Feb 23 2016 20:11:42 GMT+0200 (EET)");

var timeStamp = d.getTime();
```

Comment: and if I want to convert timestamp to `Tue Feb 23 2016 20:11:42 GMT+0200 (EET)` ? Is there any way?

Comment: can get close... `var d = new Date(timestamp)` creates a date from the timestamp. can use to `.toString()` or `.toISOString()`, or `.toGMTString()` or other methods from Date object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Conversion_getter

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it with moment, but a little unnecessary is:

```
moment(Date.parse('Tue Feb 23 2016 20:11:42 GMT+0200 (EET)')).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

change format with any other format you may desire.